# Delegate Active Directory rights

Tags: windows-server-2012

I am trying to give a user "minor" Admin rights to setup user accounts in our AD.

We have Windows Server 2012 and I already have a "Local Admin" AD Group which I use to give some users rights to logon to every Workstation, install Software ...

At the Moment we have only the Standard "users" Folder in our AD, which holds all the users, But I cannot delegate rights here, because its no OU.

What is the best Option here. I think I have to move the users in different Folders, anybody has an advice or better ideas ?

Comment: `At the Moment we have only the Standard "users" Folder in our AD, which holds all the users, But I cannot delegate rights here, because its no OU`.  Actually delegation is permitted on the builtin Users container.

Comment: Right click the Users container. Select Delegate Control from the context menu.

Comment: I already tried that, but I don´t want the "local Admins" to be able to give themself "Domain Administrators". The should only be able to add "regular" users. How Can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If your organization is going to take Active Directory security seriously, then you need a Role Based Access Control (RBAC) model. There are many ways to go about this, including using a 3rd party identity management solution. In my experience, the 3rd party solutions only shift the problem and add complexity. Instead, here is what I have found works very well:

1) Do not use the default Users container to delegate access. Creating OUs will make your life easier when it comes to delegating granular access and applying group policy. Separate your top-level OUs by tiers of administration. Anything that can be used to compromise the Domain Controllers goes in Tier-0, enterprise services go in Tier-1, and your user workstations go in Tier-2. You also have to implement policy to prevent higher tier admin accounts from logging into lower tier computers, because this would expose them to a credential theft attack. This means you would need multiple domain accounts for some administrators, depending on their role. For example, someone hired to manage the AD forest would require separate accounts for their Enterprise Admin, Domain Admin, Tier-0 server admin, Tier-1 server admin, and Tier-2 workstation admin. Someone hired at the help desk would only require Tier-2 OU administrator and Tier-2 workstation admin. The OU admin account is used to create/delete/modify AD objects for their area/department and the workstation admin account is used for remote administration of the workstations for their area/department. You need to split these roles up so that a compromise of a lesser role (the workstation admin) should not be able to compromise a higher role (the OU admin). This also means you now need to implement Privileged Access Workstations (PAW) for your higher role administrators. Are we having fun yet?

2) Establish a standardized OU structure that enforces the principal of least privilege. You have to decide if that model will be based on location, department, or a little bit of both. For Tier-2, I like to use both where the first level OU is based on the location and then the departments in that location have OUs below that. This allows a local help desk to be delegated rights to all the objects in their location, and each department with their own IT staff can be delegated rights only to their objects. The Tier-0 and Tier-1 OUs can be based on the teams running the services. It all depends on what works best for your organizational needs.

3) Each OU you create should contain a standard set of sub-OUs, security groups, ACLs, and GPOs. The reason for this is so you can easily script the creation of the OUs/Groups/ACLs/GPOs and it will always behave the same every time. Standardization is the key to keeping your sanity, trust me on this. If you later decide to change something down the road, change it for all the OU structures and update your creation process. I prefer to have these standard OUs:

- Admin (contains all administrative groups, users, and PAW computers to manage the OU)
- Computers (contains all workstation computer objects for the department; Restricted Groups GPO applied to populate local admins with the workstation admin group for this OU)
- Servers (contains all server computer objects for the department; Restricted Groups GPO applied to populate local admins with the server admin group for this OU)
- Users (contains all non-privileged user objects for the department)
- Groups (contains all non-privileged group objects for the department)

ACLs on each standard OU will be used to limit create/delete user/computer/group and read/write all property access to a standard OU administrator group associated with the OU structure. Populate the groups with the users who need that role. I strongly discourage nesting groups in any of the standard admin groups unless absolutely necessary. You can quickly lose track of who your admins are if group nesting gets out of control. I prefer to place the OU admin groups in the Admin OU at the level above to allow the help desk users the ability to designate department OU administrators. Do what works for your organization, but keep it consistent.

Here are some good sources information on this topic:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/security-best-practices/implementing-least-privilege-administrative-models

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/securing-privileged-access/securing-privileged-access-reference-material

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. As the Company grew a lot the last years, we have to Change a couple Things. With like 30 Users it wasn´t really necessary to delegate Things, with 150 users now, we def have to.
Everything has to be planned very good. Thank you very much, do you have more sources / howtos for me to have a look at ?

Comment: One of the links I provided is actually a sub-section of this article: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/securing-privileged-access/securing-privileged-access - I would suggest starting with that and also reading the related topics at the bottom. Microsoft has been putting out a lot of great guides on this topic that very few system admins are aware of. Unfortunately they leave it up to each organization to secure their environment. When you wonder why some things are left insecure, the answer is usually backward compatibility support.